# Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/server.js' upon node js deploy on google app engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, server, module, webdeploy

After a week of searching, I am not able to find a solution for an app engine deploy issue for my node.js application.

I have come to the point that I have replaced my original code with this  ["hello world" example for express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html). Running this in my local dev environment offline works well (as expected).

Then I deploy this app to my google app engine project online using the gcloud cli. That seems to work as well (no errors).

However, when I visit the app online, instead of seeing my app, I see a black page with this message: "Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.". After some digging in the google cloud console logs, I find that the error seems to be "Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/server.js'" (see more info [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzi1s.png)). I do not use such a module myself, nor do I define such a path in any of my files.

Does anyone have an idea what might be going wrong and how I can fix it? I have deployed apps successfully recently, but I'm at a loss here...

Comment: As others have suggested, You likely need to update your app.yaml file. Have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63608035/error-cannot-find-module-workspace-server-js

Answer (score 1):

As Cadet pointed out correctly, the solution was to make some changes to my app.yaml file.

[This page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element) allowed me to find the needed handlers.

Thanks a lot, Cadet.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got carried away with my [`.gcloudignore` file](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore)

I used `.gcloudignore` to ignore directories like `bin`, but I forgot that `bin` contained the file `www` which was the file run by my `package.json` "scripts">"start", this is the entry point for the app to begin running!

```
 {
  "name": "craft",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
  ...
```

If `.gcloudignore` ignores a directory, that directory is not deployed to Google App Engine, therefore I got the error (the app couldn't even be run)

```
Cannot find module '/workspace/bin/www'
```

(I assume I would get the same error locally if I deleted my bin folder fr my computer, I couldn't run the project locally either)

So the solution was to **stop ignoring** the `bin` folder from the deployments; remove (or comment-out) lines like the one below from my `.gcloudignore` file:

```
# bin/ <-- we need this folder
```

I know this is not the solution for the OP (OP says they needed changes to their [`app.yaml` handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68789337/1175496)) but it may help other people.